# GROUP_CONCAT for grouping multiple rows for a user

Tags: mysql, sql, pseudocode, group-concat

How do I create a query for grouping the users who have sent or received message from user 1.

SQL:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d6a9 for usr_msg 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ac0f for token_msg.

I have 2 tables: `token_msgs` and `user_msgs`:

[image: Image of my tables:]

I want to show the list of user ids (non repeting, like the user 2, 3 and 4 should be visible only once but in DESC order) who has sent/received message from user1 [from_id=1 OR to_id=1]. I am not able to create the logic for `GROUP_CONCAT` and not sure if i really need to join these 2 tables.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: What is your expected output? A list? Set of rows? This is unclear. Please edit your question providing this information. I don't think you need `GROUP_CONCAT` at all.

Comment: @KamilG. added the image to illustrate my expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list of users, you can use `IN` or `EXISTS`:

```
select u.*
from users u
where u.id in (select from_id from user_msgs where to_id = 1) or
      u.id in (select to_id from user_msgs where from_id = 1) or
      u.id in (select from_id from token_msgs where to_id = 1) or
      u.id in (select to_id from token_msgs where from_id = 1);
```

Comment: But this is returning all the values.. how can i limit it to 1 conversation at a time?